# Keep orientation changed for full device flutter Android 11

Tags: android, flutter, rotation, orientation, android-11

Using the following code I'm able to change the orientation of the device in app

```
void rotate(orientation) {
    if (!_isEnabled) return;

    var property = DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight;

    switch (orientation) {
      case "Portrait":
        property = DeviceOrientation.portraitUp;
        break;
      case "Reverse Portrait":
        property = DeviceOrientation.portraitDown;
        break;
      case "Landscape Left":
        property = DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft;
        break;
      case "Landscape Right":
        property = DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight;
        break;
    }

    setState(() {
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([property]);
    });
  }
```

However if I exit the app and switch to some other app the orientation changes to default portrait.

Even pressing the home button defaults the orientation.

I'm trying to keep the orientation fixed for the whole device.

I found an app on Google Play Store works till Android 10. From Android 11 it doesn't work.

I'm using a Xiaomi Redmi 9 Power with Android 11 and MIUI 12.5.5

How can I keep the orientation fixed for whole device?

Answer (score 0):

you can't and you shouldn't. Android already has a system-level orientation configuration and user may opt-in to fixed orientation. Your privileges ends when your app goes to background. Some other app want to play video in horizontal so it will be and yours has nothing to do with it. Launchers are oftenly supporting only portrait and won't ever be shown in horizontal, as its not user-friendly.